# UIImageView from JSON

Tags: objective-c, json, string, uiimageview, nslog

Data from JSON file.

```
 jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    NSString *cPhoto = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"photo"]; 
                NSURL *urlOne = [NSURL URLWithString:cPhoto];

                NSData *photoData =[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlOne];
                UIImage *imageOne = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:photoData];

                NSLog(@"%@",imageOne);
```

**NSLog view:**

```
    [10872:310156] (null)
    [10872:310156] <UIImage: 0x7f97f25cd220>, {1005, 651}
    [10872:310156] <UIImage: 0x7f97f25d59c0>, {1005, 651}
    [10872:310156] (null)
    [10872:310156] (null)
```

Why NSLog doesn't shows *.jpg format? . Only *.png file (2-nd and 3-rd). 
Thanks very much.forgive my bad English!

Comment: Is `photoData` valid the one causing issue? Is the url valid?

Comment: @Larme Yes of course. except photo get the data type number, name, surname...

Comment: I meant, is `photoData` null too when the `UIImage` is nil?

Comment: @Larme Yes. UIImage show only photos .png format

Comment: If the `NSData` is null, then it's would be normal that a `UIImage` from that `NSData` object is null too. Does the `photoData` of an jpg get the correct start of file: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Syntax_and_structure ?

Comment: in NSLog NSData *photoData shows only png

Comment: Then, `NSData` is "causing the issue", not UIImage. Do you mind showing urls for your JPG images, or at least the last components. How do you know if url is valid?

Comment: NSLog helped. I show others data.

Comment: @Larme I added NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[cPhoto stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; Now see only .jpg format ))

Comment: So, `urlOne` was nil too, then ?

Comment: I needed to show JPG format photo. I added NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[cPhoto stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; Now see only .jpg format )) ........All works. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try the below answer

```
UIImage* imageOne = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:cPhoto]]];
```

Comment: 3 lines into one. How is that's supposed to fix the issue?

Comment: It helps you definitely.

Comment: Apply this coding first.

Comment: Would you mind explaining the difference between the code from the OP and yours, and what was the issue from the OP's code?